# dplyr: Merge Rows When Column Contains Type List

Tags: r, dplyr

I am manipulating a table with `dplyr` which has a column `sta` and another column, `years`.  This second column may have *1 or more* values.

I have used **[`group_by()`](http://www.inside-r.org/node/230680)** and would now like to aggregate on `sta`, **merging the `years` column for every unique value of `sta`, *keeping only unique values*** in the `years` list.

> ### Example Data:
>
> #### Before:
>
> ```
> example <- data.frame(sta = c("AAE", "ADK", "ADK", "ADK"))
> example$years <- list(c(1994, 1995, 1996, 1997),
>                       c(1993, 1994, 1995),
>                       c(1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999), 
>                       2015)
> ```
>
> [image: Example Table]
>
> ---
>
> #### After:
>
> ```
> example <- data.frame(sta = c("AAE", "ADK"))
> example$years <- list(c(1994, 1995, 1996, 1997),
>                       c(1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2015))
> ```
>
> [image: Example Result]

This problem seems really trivial, but I cannot seem to identify the appropriate syntax to handle this type of row-collapse.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: In strictly `dplyr` you could use `example %>% group_by(sta) %>% summarise(years = paste(years, collapse = ", "))` (this is untested as I'm on mobile, but fairly confident it works. Hence it only being a comment)

Comment: @brittenb  Something like in the answer?

Comment: @Pascal I'm confused by your comment. At the time of posting the comment, the answer below only mentioned using `tidyr`. Are you saying they're too similar?

Comment: @brittenb  Simply asking, as there is little difference. Was wondering which is more efficient, if any. And yours is only a comment, so no problem.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yeah, it was just a quick alternative on my ride home from work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with tidyr's `unnest` and `nest` operations. To keep only unique years, you can add a `distinct` step in between.

```
library(tidyr)
example %>%
  unnest(years) %>%
  distinct(sta, years) %>%
  nest(years)
```

If you'd rather not use tidyr, you could alternatively use `group_by` and `do`, with the `do` step performing the concatenation and unique steps:

```
example %>%
  group_by(sta) %>%
  do(years = unique(unlist(.$years))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

(The last `ungroup` step is to keep it from being a rowwise-grouped data frame).

Comment: Your tidyr example doesn't seem to work, but the `group_by` & `do` combination works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @DonScott The tidyr example works with your example dataset (with tidyr 0.3.1). Do you perhaps have other columns in the data besides `sta` and `years`?

Comment: When I run unnest() on my dataset, the column is not properly unnested.  Interestingly, if I use `unnest` after your second example it works perfectly.  If the native option didn't work I would look into it more, but I suspect it is a type issue with my larger dataset.